# Change in enthalpy equation

Tags: thermodynamics, enthalpy

If the formula for change in enthalpy is ΔH=ΔU+pΔV, and ΔU = q - pΔV then shouldn't the formula be simplified to ΔH = q regardless of whether the volume or pressure is constant? Is this only true when pressure and volume is constant?

Comment: The general formula is ΔH=ΔU+Δ(pV)

Comment: Just wondering, would the change of enthalpy be equal to q when volume is constant?

Comment: If pressure is constant as well, then yes.

Answer (score 1):

The general formula is $\Delta H=\Delta U + \Delta (pV)$.

Since $\Delta U=q_v$ (heat at constant volume), then $\Delta H=q_V+V\Delta p$, so no, heat at constant volume does not equal enthalpy, unless p is constant, which just brings you back to the original relation $\Delta H = q_p$.